# kubectl kubectl apply do nothing

Tags: kubernetes, deployment

I have existing deployments in k8s, I would like to update container, I updated docker image tag (new unique id) in deployment and run:

```
kubectl apply -f testdeploy.yml --namespace=myapp
```

Output is: `deployment.apps/fakename configured`

But nothing happens.

When I run `kubectl get pods --namespace=myapp` I can see only one old pod with old age.

Sometimes is working, sometimes not, why?

What is wrong?

Comment: I can try to add `ImagePullPolicy: Always` as @adp suggested but just the fact you are updating, the image the current pod should be deleted and a new one with the new image should spinning up. I did the same here and it worked to me.

Comment: Since you had update the image tag, it would have fetched the image if the container runtime doesn't have it else it will res-use the existing image. Did you checked the events when updated deployment was applied and any errors there? Also `imagePullPolicy: Always` isn't a good option unless you're updating the same docker version with new code (which is bad design) or using the `latest` tag.

Comment: SInce the deployment is configured, the pod should restart with the new image... please post your deployment spec. Have you tried to use `ImagePullPolicy: Always` as suggested?

Comment: Do `kubectl get deploy <deployment-name> -o wide` to see the configured image. Is it updated after `apply`?

Answer (score 4):

try describing the deployment and see the events

```
kubectl describe <deployment-name> --namespace=myapp
```

or

```
kubectl get events --namespace=myapp
```

to understand what is happening.

try checking whether new replicas has been created for changed deployment container image.

```
kubectl get rs -n myapp
```

check the number of replicas expected example when you do `kubectl get rs`:

```
NAME                                DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
<deployment-name>-58ffbb8b76         0         0         0       10s
```

maybe few more details would be helpful to understand why was nothing happening when you try to deploy.

kubernetes has nice documentation check this.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-application-introspection/

Answer (score 3):

Try with adding `ImagePullPolicy: Always` as the below:

```
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: <YOUR_IMAGE>:<YOUR_TAG>
        imagePullPolicy: Always
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to delete your deployment `kubectl delete -f testdeploy.yml --namespace=myapp`
and then create it again `kubectl apply -f testdeploy.yml --namespace=myapp`
it will fetch the new image, or you can edit your deployment file as shown below and introduce rollingupdate and then when you update your image you can simply type `kubectl rollout restart deploy  deployment_name_mentioned_in_manifest -n namespace` this will provision a new pod while the old stays and fetch the new image, once that is done old pod will get deleted and the new pod will have the latest image.

Example with the manifest file below if i want to pull latest image i will type `kubectl rollout restart deploy nginx -n test`

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: nginx
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
      maxSurge: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name:  nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          hostPort: 80
        - containerPort: 443
          hostPort: 443
        readinessProbe:
          tcpSocket:
            port: 443
            port: 80
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 5
```